# How to set string "dd/mm/yyyy" as the value of the default date displayed in jquery ui calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery UI calendar and needs default date to that is displayed to be "dd/mm/yyyy".
On using setDate("dd/mm/yyyy"), it sets default date to be current date and displays it.

Please suggest.

Comment: But have you checked relevant plugin documentation???

Comment: Fixed it by setting the value of the datepicker input field as "dd/mm/yyyy". Thanks